# Ant Tasks for Amazon EC2/S3?

Tags: java, ant, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, task

Does anyone know of a good library providing Ant tasks for performing operations against Amazon EC2/S3?  I'd like to leverage S3 for deployment of new WAR files for my applications, and figured Ant would be a good way to keep simplify the process and keep everything consistent.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [CSS Labs's Ant extensions](http://cssinnovations.blogspot.com/2008/05/application-deployment-on-ec2-made_29.html).

Comment: Alas, the site is still active, but not the download: The specified bucket does not exist

Answer (score 3):

[aws-ant-task](https://github.com/corley/aws-ant-task) is stable and actively maintained as of October 2012.  And it works super!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Ant tasks to interface with Amazon Web Services](http://code.google.com/p/awstasks/)

Comment: I saw that library, but it only seems to provide "delete" and "upload" capabilities.  I was hoping for something more full-featured.

Comment: One stroke against this library so far is the performance - 8 hours to upload data to S3, where s3cmd takes 20 minutes for the same data.

Answer (score 1):

You could try munging some [Ruby AWS](http://amazon-ec2.rubyforge.org/) libraries into Ant with Jruby.  In fact, it would be easiest to use Jruby to expose the Ant tasks (which are the good bit of Ant, IMHO) to some Ruby deploy scripts.  No XML.